# Cache invalidation Postgres NOTIFY vs. polling

Tags: java, postgresql, caching, jdbc

We have a Java application which caches all the info (~5000 entries in 7 tables) from a Postgres database. The problem is that the database is updated externally and the cache needs to know when to be invalidated. To be noted that we are not expecting many inserts/updates.

Postgres provides a great solution for this through Listen/Notify and Trigger on insert/update; the only problem is with the JDBC driver for Postgres which [does not know to listen on notifications](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/listennotify.html) asynchronously and requires polling and haven't found a solution to listen asynchronously from Java.

The question is how to design the cache update triggering in this case, to achieve the best performance and limit the amount time the cache is inconsistent. Is the above described mechanism worth it (create triggers for each table and then separate channels for listen/notify and polling for notifications) or would it be fast to create a query like this `select * from table where update_timestamp > ?` and the parameter given be that of the latest cache update timestamp (assume the column is indexed).

In simple terms, is notify/listen with polling worth it or is querying with polling faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the notify frequency. If you get 100 notifies per second, it may be "slower" (=needing more CPU resources) then polling, since you have more OS context switches.

Comment: Then it depends on your business need how far you are allowed to lag behind. If you need to update instantly polling every 1-5 seconds is more costly then the notify approach (BTW: update_timestamp needs btree index, of course)

Comment: Question: Is the other application a Java application, too? Can't you use something like JPA in both applications, which exactly cares for caching and consistency?

Comment: The problem is that notify also needs polling since JDBC does not support an asynchronous mechanism The other application is Erlang; we don't use JPA since we need performance and JPA query cache (in EclipseLink) has very poor performance compared to direct map based caching.

Comment: Idea 1: Do an asynchronous notify from your erlang application to the Java application yourself, e.g. by a http request.

Comment: Idea 2: Use the blocking of transactions. E.g. have a long running transaction access a table from erlang and do then again the same from Java. When the erlang appication does a commit also end the long running "notify" transaction. Then the Java application waiting for the table lock will run. You need to check your transaction isolation levels and whether there are some timeouts involved. I think you can have a check of this with a quick experiment. If working it is the most elegant solution, because you don't need any special stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For asynchronous notifications go for the pgjdbc-ng 0.6 driver.

http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/

It supports async notifications, without polling.